# Make absolute positioned div 100% of page height

Tags: jquery, css, height, absolute

I have a div with `position: absolute` that I want to be tall enough that it reaches the bottom of the page when I scroll all the way down. In other words, it should extend the full height of the document page (not just the window).

My understanding is that viewport height (`vh`) isn't useful here because it only extends elements to the full height of the window.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jygrinberg/qsyLqns7/4/

I'm fine with a solution that uses JavaScript or jQuery.

**EDIT:** The page contents may be taller than the contents of the div (I updated the fiddle accordingly).

Comment: If you want it to keep going, you can't have two different div's since the it's only styling the one with that ID. If you want different div's then change the '#full-height' selector to 'div'.

Comment: Sorry, your comment isn't clear. In my Fiddle, the "page content" div corresponds to content on my webpage. The "full-height" div corresponds to a div I would like to be as tall as all the content on my page.

Comment: So you want the color blue to be the whole background of the page? Or simply a little portion of it?

Comment: The blue div should extend the full height of the page.

Comment: But even if you add more content, you want the background to always be blue correct?

Comment: Yes, the background of the blue #full-height div should extend the full height of the page.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background: #5ae;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #5ae;
}
```

If that doesn't work try to delete the `bottom: 0` line.

Comment: Your update doesn't work. The #full-height div needs to extend the full height. You just made the body background blue.

Comment: So you want the 2 div's to be side by side, and the right one to have blue background it that right?

Comment: All I want is the #full-height div to extend the full height of the page. In the Fiddle example, I inputted sample "page content" <p> tags to represent my webpage's content. The #full-height div should extend to be the exact height of the page content, however tall the page content may be.

Comment: You can't extend that div because it simply has no more content. You have to do that in a different way. That's why I asked if you want them to be side by side

Comment: A div doesn't need content to be a certain height. For example, <div style="height:100px; width:100px"></div> has no content but has a height of 100px.

Comment: That is correct but if you don't set the height it will simply fit with the content in it.